# Getting a file from a server using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, ajax

So, I wrote some JavaScript to grab an xml file from my desktop and display it on an html page. However, I now have added my xml file to a webserver (mongoose). I want to call the file from that server, but whenever I call the file from the server it dosen't work, but when I call it from my desktop it loads fine.

I want to swap

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","Devices.xml",false);
```

with

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:8080/Devices.xml",false);
```

Here is the code

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xmlhttp.open("GET","Devices.xml",false);
  xmlhttp.send();
  xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 


  // the <Device> list
  x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Device');

  // make a function that extracts the attributes out of a Node
  function getDeviceAttributes(dvc) {
    var name = dvc.getAttribute("name");
    var uuid = dvc.getAttribute("uuid");
    var id   = dvc.getAttribute("id");
    return "<p>name: " + name + "<br> uuid: " + uuid + "<br> id: "+ id + "</p>";
  }

  // loop through the list
  // assuming order doesn’t matter
  var txt = '';
  for (var i = x.length; i--;) {
    txt += getDeviceAttributes(x[i]);
  }

  //show the result on page load
  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("showDevices").innerHTML = txt;
  };

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id='showDevices'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know how I can get this to work?

I have been told to use AJAX and Jquery, but I have no idea how to or even where to begin.

Comment: Are you serving the page that grabs that file from the same webserver? if not you might be encountering some same origin issues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are repeating a lot of work that jQuery can do for you.  Check out the documentation for the [Get request method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

So something like this:

```
$.get('http://localhost:8080/Devices.xml', function(data) {
    $('#showDevices').html(data);
});
```

I believe that is the jQuery for what you are trying to do.  Hope that helps.

-Charlie

Just some generic advice, you could also use the .load() ajax function if you didn't want to parse the response and this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("showDevices").innerHTML = txt;
};
```

can be done in jQuery like this `$("#showDevices").html(txt);`